# Solve $\cos x-\sin(2x)=0$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

Solve $\cos x-\sin(2x)=0$

I did:

$$\cos x=\color{blue}{\sin(\pi /2-x)}$$

therefore:

$$\color{blue}{\sin(\pi /2-x)}=\sin(2x)$$

> Can I do that:??
>
> now to solve only for $\pi/2-x=2x$
>
> so $x=\pi/6+2\pi k$

Comment: hint: $\sin 2x=2\sin x \cos x$. For what you did, you need to include $+2\pi k$ a line above... and also not forget that sines are not only equal when arguments are equal. You are forgetting there are always two solutions on the unit circle. So you need to write both cases to get two sets of solutiosn.

Comment: Why the downvote? This question is asked properly!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Slightly differently,

$$\cos x=\cos\left(\frac\pi2-2x\right)$$

yields

$$\pm x=\frac\pi2-2x+2k\pi$$ or

$$x=\frac{4k+1}{4\pm2}\pi.$$

Answer (score 4):

The first step is ok, but for the second we have that
$$\sin A=\sin B\iff A+B=(2k+1)\pi\text{ or }A-B=2k\pi$$

Then, from the equality $\sin(\pi/2-x)=\sin 2x$ we get two sets of solutions:

- $\pi/2-x+2x=(2k+1)\pi$
- $2x-(\pi/2-x)=2k\pi$

Comment: What about $\pi/6$? and $5\pi/6$?

Answer (score 2):

Also, $$\cos x =\sin 2x \Rightarrow \cos x(1-2\sin x)=0 $$ $$ \cos x=0 \mid \sin x=\frac{1}{2}$$ where $\mid$ stands for "or". This can be easily solved.

Also, you can see that $\frac{5\pi}{6}$ is clearly a solution that is **not included by your approach**. Hope it helps.

---

**EDIT**: Expanding on @ajotatxe's one-liner on why $\sin x= \sin y \nRightarrow x=y$:

If $$\sin x-\sin y=0 \Rightarrow 2\cos \frac{x+y}{2}\sin \frac{x-y}{2} =0$$ Then solving, we have $$\frac{x+y}{2} = (2n+1)\frac{\pi}{2} \space\space\space\text{or}\space\space \frac{x-y}{2} = n\pi \space\space\space\text{where}\space\space n\in \mathbb Z$$ $$\Rightarrow x=(2n+1)\pi-y \space\space\space \text{or} \space\space x= 2n\pi + y \space\space\space\text{where}\space\space n\in \mathbb Z$$

Answer (score 1):

Cos x -sin(2x)= 0   implies that cos x- 2 sin x cos x=0      cos x (1- 2sin x) = 0
It means   cos x=0  or sin x=1/2
   Which gives answer  x = 2n pi +- 90`    or x= n pi +(-1)^n pi/6    I hope it helps you

Answer (score 0):

$$\cos\left(x\right)-\sin\left(2x\right)=0\space\Longleftrightarrow\space\cos\left(x\right)=\cos\left(2x-\frac{\pi}{2}\right)$$

Take the inverse cosine of both sides:

$$x=2\pi\text{k}_1+2x-\frac{\pi}{2}\space\space\space\vee\space\space\space x=2\pi\text{k}_2-2x+\frac{\pi}{2}$$

Where $\text{k}_1\space\wedge\space\text{k}_2\in\mathbb{Z}$

Comment: What about $\pi/6$? and $5\pi/6$?